# Передача данных между компонентами angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular2

Добрый день всем. Перед мной стоит задача на angular 2.

Есть компонент, к примеру, tree-structure в котором лежит объект:

```
{
"id": 1,
"nodes": [
  {
    "id": 11,
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 111,
        "nodes": []
      },
      {
        "id": 112,
        "nodes": []
      },
      {
        "id": 113,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": 1131,
            "nodes": []
          },
          {
            "id": 1132,
            "nodes": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

У этого компонента есть дочерний компонент tree-view. 
Задача заключается вот в чем:

Из родительского компонента передавать уровни этого объекта, а дочерний должен их отображать в зависимости от вложенности.
Нельзя передать весь объект сразу и потом отрисовать, нужно передавать и отрисовывать динамически. Переслали туда уровень, отрисовали. В данном случае можно создать дерево из айдишников.
Я так полагаю это нужно делать через @Input ?

Answer (score 0):

У дочернего компонента TreeVeiw делаем примерно такой шаблончик:

```
<li><span>{{ id }}</span>
  <ul *ngIf="nodes.lenght">
    <tree-view [nodes]='nodes'></tree-view>
  </ul>
</li>
```

в самом компоненте как вы правильно заметили делаем 
`@Input() nodes: any[];`
И все отработает как вы хотите. 
И у родительского контейнера делаем схожий шаблон, только завернутый в `ul`